# Removing spaces from a string in C Memory fault

Tags: c

I'm writing a simple code for removing spaces from a string in C however I get the following message after compiling: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, adresss=....).
It's coming from the line '*temp = *str' however I don't understand why? How can I fix it?

```
void removeSpaces(char * str)
{
  char * temp = str;

  while (*str != '\0') {
    if (*str != ' ') {
      *temp = *str;
      temp++;
     }
    str++;
  }
  *temp = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Hint: compare `char * temp = str` and `*temp = *str`.

Comment: How did you call `removeSpaces()`?  Did you pass it a string literal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function works fine when passed a string declared like this

```
char s[] = "Hallo  World!";
```

but if you declared the string like this, as a pointer to string literal

```
char *s = "Hallo  World!";
```

you are not supposed to modify the string.

Comment: @WeatherVane impressive answer. Actually I am contempleting your answers and it seems there is so much I can learn. Thanks for being here. Will check out your answers time and again to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are passing an string literal. `temp` and `str` pointing to same string literal. With statement `*temp = *str;` you are modifying the that literal which should not be modified.

To fix the problem allocate memory for `temp`

```
char *temp = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
```

Comment: He can modify directly the same string

Comment: I suggest mentioning about `strdup` here. Also, about `free`ing the allocated memory.

Comment: It's not a problem to modify the same string, in fact, it's better.